# Emphasize greek letters within LyX's (Program) Listing

Tags: listings, lyx

I include greek letters in LyX's Program Listing (using `mathescape=true`) and want to emphasize them (with color & bold, using `emph` and `emphstyle`), but I can't get it to work; I geuss that it cannot recognize the `$alpha$` symbol in this way, so it does not color and bold it and just shows it plain. Is there any way do to it properly?

please find below the `.tex` code for the listing part:

```
\begin_inset listings
lstparams "mathescape=true,emph={[3]$\alpha$,α,alpha,\alpha},emphstyle={[3]\color{blue}\textbf}"
inline true
status open

\begin_layout Plain Layout

$
\backslash
alpha$
\end_layout

\end_inset
```

as well as a complete minimal example:

```
#LyX 2.3 created this file. For more info see http://www.lyx.org/
\lyxformat 544
\begin_document
\begin_header
\save_transient_properties true
\origin unavailable
\textclass article
\begin_preamble
\usepackage{culmus}

\end_preamble
\use_default_options true
\maintain_unincluded_children false
\language hebrew
\language_package default
\inputencoding auto
\fontencoding global
\font_roman "default" "David CLM"
\font_sans "default" "David CLM"
\font_typewriter "default" "Courier New"
\font_math "auto" "auto"
\font_default_family default
\use_non_tex_fonts true
\font_sc false
\font_osf false
\font_sf_scale 100 100
\font_tt_scale 100 100
\use_microtype true
\use_dash_ligatures true
\graphics default
\default_output_format default
\output_sync 0
\bibtex_command default
\index_command default
\paperfontsize 11
\spacing other 1.3
\use_hyperref true
\pdf_bookmarks true
\pdf_bookmarksnumbered false
\pdf_bookmarksopen false
\pdf_bookmarksopenlevel 1
\pdf_breaklinks false
\pdf_pdfborder true
\pdf_colorlinks false
\pdf_backref false
\pdf_pdfusetitle true
\papersize default
\use_geometry true
\use_package amsmath 1
\use_package amssymb 1
\use_package cancel 1
\use_package esint 1
\use_package mathdots 1
\use_package mathtools 1
\use_package mhchem 1
\use_package stackrel 1
\use_package stmaryrd 1
\use_package undertilde 1
\cite_engine basic
\cite_engine_type default
\biblio_style plain
\use_bibtopic false
\use_indices false
\paperorientation portrait
\suppress_date false
\justification true
\use_refstyle 1
\use_minted 0
\boxbgcolor #c5ffac
\index Index
\shortcut idx
\color #008000
\end_index
\leftmargin 3.18cm
\topmargin 2.54cm
\rightmargin 3.18cm
\bottommargin 2.54cm
\secnumdepth 3
\tocdepth 3
\paragraph_separation indent
\paragraph_indentation 0bp
\is_math_indent 0
\math_numbering_side default
\quotes_style english
\dynamic_quotes 0
\papercolumns 1
\papersides 1
\paperpagestyle default
\bullet 0 0 7 -1
\tracking_changes false
\output_changes false
\html_math_output 0
\html_css_as_file 0
\html_be_strict false
\end_header

\begin_body

\begin_layout Standard
\begin_inset listings
lstparams "mathescape=true,emph={[3]$\alpha$,α,alpha,\alpha},emphstyle={[3]\color{blue}\textbf}"
inline true
status open

\begin_layout Plain Layout

$
\backslash
alpha$
\end_layout

\end_inset


\end_layout

\end_body
\end_document
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You’re trying to mix math-mode and text-mode commands in a way that’s not quite legal.  Your options include:

- Load `\usepackage[LGR, T1]` and `\usepackage{\textalpha}`, then use the text-mode command `\textalpha`.  This requires PDFTeX.
- Load `\usepackage{alphabeta}` and use eiither `\alpha` or `\textalpha` in text mode. This requires PDFTeX.
- Load `unicode-math` and a font that supports Greek (such as New Computer Modern, Computer Modern Unicode, Libertinus, etc.) and use `\mupalpha` in text mode.  This requires LuaTeX or XeTeX.
- Load an upright OML-encoded bold math font as `\mathbf` and use that in math mode.  The easiest way to do that is through `isomath`, but you can also use `\SetMathAlphabet{\mathbf}{normal}{OML}{mdbch}{b}{n}`.  The only upright fonts that support this are the Math Design fonts, Charter, Utopia or Garamond, but you have more choices for a bold italic `\mathbfit`.
- The above also works if you use `\boldsymbol{\mathrm{\alpha}}` after `\SetMathAlphabet{\mathrm}{bold}{OML}{mdbch}{b}{n}`.
- Use a math alphabet from `unicode-math`, such as `\symbfup`.
- Declare new math alphabets in `unicode-math` with `\setmathfontface`, e.g. `\setmathfontface\mathemph{NewCMMono10-Bold.otf}[Color=blue]`.